# C++ << operator overloading and templates with Arduino

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, arduino

I'm working on an arduino project where I have been using the following template for printing various data types with the << operator

```
template<class T>
inline Print &operator <<(Print &obj, T arg)
{ obj.print(arg); return obj; }
```

Which has been fine until trying to process char arrays stored with Arduinos P macro which stores data in flash instead of ram

```
//params stored in flash using P() from webduino library
P(CT_PLAIN) = "text/plain\n";
server << CT_PLAIN;
```

Which results in the compiler error

```
httpServer.h : : In function 'Print& operator<<(Print&, T) [with T = const prog_uchar*]':
httpServer.cpp : instantiated from here
httpServer.h : call of overloaded 'print(const prog_uchar*&)' is ambiguous
```

Although the following compiles

```
//params stored in flash using P() from webduino library
P(CT_PLAIN) = "text/plain\n";
server.printP(CT_PLAIN);
```

I have tried to create a << operator overload but I don't completely understand the syntax and methodology, I have been researching for several hours to no avail and would highly appreciate any feedback.

```
 WebServer &operator <<(WebServer &server,const prog_uchar *str)
 { server.printP(str); }

 template<class T>
 inline Print &operator <<(Print &obj, T arg)
 { obj.print(arg); return obj; }
```

Although I still get the same compiler error.

The declaration of WebServer::printP is

```
 void printP(const prog_uchar *str);
```

Any feedback and assistance would be highly appreciated!

The complete compiler error:

```
 Compiling 'webapp' for 'Arduino Mega 2560 or Mega ADK'
 httpServer.h : : In function 'Print& operator<<(Print&, T) [with T = const prog_uchar*]':
 httpServer.cpp : instantiated from here
 httpServer.h : call of overloaded 'print(const prog_uchar*&)' is ambiguous
 Print.h : print(const String&) <near match>
 Print.h : print(const char*) <near match>
 Print.h : print(char) <near match>
 Print.h : print(unsigned char, int) <near match>
 Print.h : print(int, int) <near match>
 Print.h : print(unsigned int, int) <near match>
 Print.h : print(long int, int) <near match>
 Print.h : print(long unsigned int, int) <near match>
 Error compiling
```

Additionally the definition of WebServer::printP

```
 void WebServer::printP(const prog_uchar *str)
 {
 // copy data out of program memory into local storage, write out in
 // chunks of 32 bytes to avoid extra short TCP/IP packets
   uint8_t buffer[32];
   size_t bufferEnd = 0;

   while (buffer[bufferEnd++] = pgm_read_byte(str++))
   {
     if (bufferEnd == 32)
     {
       m_client.write(buffer, 32);
       bufferEnd = 0;
     }
   }

   // write out everything left but trailing NUL
   if (bufferEnd > 1)
     m_client.write(buffer, bufferEnd - 1);
 }
```

Comment: Is it really `server.printP(CT_PLAIN);` or did you mean `server.print(P(CT_PLAIN));`? In the first case, what's the type of `P(CT_PLAIN)`, and what's `printP` signature?

Comment: Yes I double checked its `server.printP(CT_PLAIN);`
`CT_PLAIN is static const prog_uchar CT_PLAIN[12] = "text/plain\n"`
and the 
`printP`method is
`void WebServer::printP(const prog_uchar *str)`

Comment: What is the relation between `Print` and `WebServer` ?

Comment: `WebServer` class deceleration `class WebServer: public Print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WebServer &operator <<(WebServer &server,const prog_uchar *str)
 { server.printP(str); return server;}

 template<class T>
 inline WebServer &operator <<(WebServer &obj, T arg)
 { obj.print(arg); return obj; }
```

The overload didnt return a type and to resolve ambiguity from the template it was changed to the subclass

Answer (score 5):

The thing is in your first example, you are calling `printP(const prog_uchar*)` with an argument of type `const prog_uchar[12]` which is trivially convertible to `const prog_uchar*`.

When you use `operator<<`, you are calling the function `print()` with your object of type `const prog_uchar[12]` but you don't have any `print` overload suitable for this type. So, the compiler looks for the different `print` overloads and takes the most suitable. However, there is not only one "most suitable" overload in your case, but 8 of them, hence the detailed error message you have in the end.

A solution to your problem would be to explicitly cast what you are trying to print to `const char*`:

```
P(CT_PLAIN) = "text/plain\n";
server << (const char*) CT_PLAIN;
```

Another solution would be to provide to `print` an overload for `const prog_uchar*`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Morwenn, it makes perfect sense now appreciate the excellent explanation!

Comment: I thought I understood although this solution doesn't work because of the P macro. Looking at how WebServer::printP operates I believe it uses the individual characters and looks them up in the processors flash memory, typecasting like this will just return a char array of flash memory points. Sorry for my bad explanation, I'm learning this as I go along.

I have added the definition of WebServer::printP which probably explains better than what I wrote above

Comment: @TimKalinowski I will try to look at it later if you don't find the solution meanwhile, I'm busy right now, sorry^^"

Comment: No problem, I highly appreciate the time you've put in already!